# v-bind not working on attribute with Vue3 ESM CDN import

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to use v-bind to create a "data-*" attribute but I probably misunderstood something because what I try doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```html
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'

    const idPartenaire = createApp({
        data() {
            return {
            id: 2222,
            test:"un_test"
            }
        }
    }).mount('#idpartenaire')
</script>

<div id="idpartenaire" v-bind:data-test="test">ID du partenaire : {{ id }}</div>
```

The result I expect is this :

```html
<div id="idpartenaire" data-test="un_test">ID du partenaire : 2222</div>
```

But what I get is this:

```html
<div id="idpartenaire" v-bind:data-test="test" data-v-app="">ID du partenaire : 2222</div>
```

Anyone could explain me where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it looks like you cannot have attributes with direct state on the mounted HTML element.
A solution is to nest a block inside of the element you're mounting the Vue instance on.

This works as expected

```html
<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        id: 2222,
        test:"un_test"
      }
    }
  }).mount('#idpartenaire')
</script>

<div id="idpartenaire"> <!-- ❌ doesn't work here directly -->
  <div :data-test="id"> <!-- ✅ okay here -->
    ID du partenaire : {{ id }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like this caveat only applied with Vue 3 but not Vue 2. While Vue 3 provides a lot of improvement but this kind of caveat is really annoying.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon CDNs are not a good approach for anything deployed on production anyway, so I'd say that this is a nice issue.

Comment: One of the selling point of Vue is it can be used without a build system like jQuery. This kind of caveat is causing a problem with this use case because it need a wrapper element.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon having a wrapper is not a big deal. You should weight the drawbacks of using a CDN, that will make you reconsider the importance of a wrapper caveat overall. `petite-vue` may not have such issues I suppose. Still, I recommend having a build step so that your visitors have a nice experience (Vite is not difficult to configure).

Comment: It not a big deal for SPA but for non-SPA it is annoying because the component cannot be mounted directly on the target element. The problem with build tool is it not work well with non-JS SSR.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon if your project is not a super interactive app, there is no point in having an SPA. If you want to have SSR on top of Vue, you should probably give a try to Nuxt. The whole mounting/rehydration process is quite bad for the performance, so if that could be avoided, that's for the best for sure. Vite works for Rails, Laravel, and plenty of other tools. So you could integrate it directly with your backend or have 2 steps, one for your backend and one for your frontend. Anyway, a build step is quite important nowadays to have decent Web Core Vitals. TLDR: use a CDN only for debugging

Comment: Nuxt forced you to rewrite your app in JS. It is no point to continue this discussion because your solutions is not feasible for my problem. I already downgraded to Vue 2 and happy with that. I know the build system provides a lot of features but you need to understand that it is not suitable for some use case.